# Regex to change all past a certain pattern to Uppercase

Tags: regex, vim, uppercase

I have an xml file that has a value like

```
 JOBNAME="JBDSR14353_Some_other_Descriptor"
```

I am looking for an expression that will go through the file and change all of the characters in the quotes to Uppercase letters. Is there a Regex expression that will search for JOBNAME="Anything within the quotes" and change them to uppercase?  Or a command that will find JOBNAME= and change all on that line to uppercase letters? I know that can just do a search for JOBNAME= and then use a VU command in vim to throw the line to uppercase store that to a macro and run that, but I was wondering if there was a way to get this done with a regex??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an alternative with `:substitute`, as you had originally intended. This works better than @Zach's solution with `gU_` when there's other text in the line:

```
:%s/JOBNAME="[^"]\+"/\U&/g
```

- `"[^"]\+"` matches the quoted text (non-greedily by matching only non-quotes inside, to handle multiple quotes in a line)
- `\U` turns the remainder of the replacement uppercase
- for simplicity, the entire match (`&`) is uppercased here, but one could have also used *capture groups* (`\(...\)`), or match limiting with `\zs`

Comment: Why do you prefer `[^"]\+` to the non greedy match `.\{-}`?

Comment: @FDinoff: It doesn't matter here; in more complex patterns, it could.

Comment: Thank you this works great too! and even though Zachs answer does solve my problem as well, I am changing yours to the correct answer as my question did ask for a Regex.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `:g` command which executes a command on lines that match a pattern:

```
:g/JOBNAME/norm! gU_
```

This will execute the `gU_`, which capitalizes all letters on a line, on all the lines that match `JOBNAME`

If there are other things on the same line that you don't want to capitalize, here is a solution for only the words in quotes:

```
:g/JOBNAME/norm! f"gU;
```

`f"` goes to the next quote. `gU` capitalizes with a motion. The motion used is `;` which searches for the next `"` (repeats the last `f` command).

Comment: Nice. Just a suggestion, but I always use `normal!` in this context so that any mappings are ignored. (Plus some extra info at `:help case`.)

Answer (score 2):

To do this with substitution you can use the `\U` atom which makes everything after it uppercase.

```
:%s/JOBNAME="\zs.*\ze"/\U&
```

`\zs` and `\ze` mark the start and end of the match and `&` is the whole match. This means that only the part between quotes is replaced.

Comment: Thanks this works well too. If one wanted to convert this into a sed command to say put it in a script to use would it be much different? As it is written now it gives an unterminated s command
          sed -i 's/JOBNAME="zs.*\ze"/\U&' file_name  
I tried adding the /g to the end and it did not complain however it did not change anything in the file.

Comment: @Archer783 `\zs` and `\ze` are vim specific

Comment: Ahh is see. Ingo Karkat's solution will work with sed